# In horse breeding, what is the female equivalent of putting a horse out "to stud"?

Tags: verbs, terminology

The BBC today has a story about a champion racehorse who has just retired

> She will now be retired to stud

https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/horse-racing/47918578

This doesn't really scan for me. It feels like being put out "to stud" is something stallions do.

A little reading says that the female equivalent of a stud, is a broodmare. But there seems to be no common usage of a horse being put out "to mare", "to brood" or "to broodmare".

Was my initial assumption incorrect and both stallions and mares are retired "to stud"? Or is there a female specific term?

Comment: Out to be studded? Oh wait, that’s mail, not mares…

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[*Stud*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/stud#etymonline_v_22212) comes from a Germanic root meaning a herd of horses or the place where horses are kept for breeding. The same root is behind the Modern German *Stute*, ‘mare’, *Gestüt*, ‘stud farm’, and the name of the city of *Stuttgart*.

A [*stud farm*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stud_farm) or [*(horse) stud*](http://www.spanishhorsestud.com/) is still where horses are selectively bred. Before artificial insemination, owners of mares wishing to have their animals *covered by* (‘bred with’, since [1530s](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cover#etymonline_v_19193)) a particular stallion would pay a *stud fee* and bring the mare to the stallion’s location, which was likely to be a stud farm. All such pairings are recorded in a *stud book*. The location, *stud*, and the activity taking place there, breeding, began to merge.

In the early 19th c., the word began to denote a breeding stallion. Thus the term *out to stud* is gendered for many speakers — and the reason *stud* was transferred to certain human males by the end of the century.

> If your selection of a stallion is not for purchase but rather for use on one of your mares, you will also be interested in the management at the [*stud*](https://books.google.de/books?id=ieAcCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA124&dq=stud+mare&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisiPGTks3hAhVhzqYKHRP9BP0Q6AEINjAD) at which he stands. There are several things that will concern most owners selecting a stud to send their mare to, and these will be discussed in turn. — Mina Davies Morel, *Equine Reproductive Physiology, Breeding and Stud Management*, 2015.

Stallions available for breeding are said to be *standing at stud* or *at stud service*. It makes economic and practical sense for the mares to come to the stallion, who in a given season can cover a number of mares, and that horsebreeders would offer their best breeding stallions on a stud farm.

The financial outlay can be considerable. In 2017, for instance, it was reported that a thoroughbred stallion covered up to 125 mares a year for a stud fee of [$300,000 each](https://www.cnbc.com/2017/06/07/how-americas-most-valuable-stallion-makes-35-million-a-year.html).

A broodmare is also called a [*stud mare*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/de/worterbuch/englisch/stud-mare), and a mare as well as a stallion can be  *retired to stud* after a racing career:

> Chesnut Annie, one of the most successful point-to-pointers of the last decade, has been [*retired to stud*](https://www.horseandhound.co.uk/news/top-point-to-point-mare-retired-to-stud-493442) at the age of 14. The tough, gutsy mare … brought in the crowds wherever she ran. She was the winner of 38 of her 58 races between the flags and notched up a further 14 placings. She also won two hunter chases.
> Annie will be covered by the successful thoroughbred sire, Dr Massini, who is responsible for many top performers including the high class Grade 2 winner Rocky Creek. — *Horse and Hound*, 15 May 2015.

This almost reads like a wedding announcement.

*Out to stud*, however, is almost always associated with male animals, though a few horsebreeders  do use the term for mares:

> If you're planning on sending your mare [*out to stud*](https://forums.horseandhound.co.uk/threads/dont-be-fooled-by-defra-approved-ai-centres.87204), or to an AI centre, you'll obviously want to make sure that the place is run well. — *Horse and Hound* Forum post, 31 July 2007.
>
> They don't want to have a lag time for the mare to raise her foal, so they put a lesser mare [*out to stud*](https://dellanischoice.wordpress.com/tag/horses/) at the same time and use her for milk. — Dellani’s Choice (blog), 11 Dec. 2011.

One horse enthusiast finds this usage objectionable:

> At this point I'm going with Eurodressage because apprently horse and hounds (sic) think you put a mare [*out to stud*](https://www.chronofhorse.com/forum/forum/discussion-forums/dressage/76348-rip-blue-hors-matinee). — Chronicle of the Horse, forum post, 25 Jan. 2010.

The vastly more frequent expression for mares is simply  *to breed*:

> Perhaps the ideal age [*to breed a mare*](https://www.equisearch.com/articles/appropriate-breeding-age) for the first time is when she is 3 to foal at 4, or 4 to foal at 5. However, there are many factors that can change that ideal age. — Equisearch.com, 11 Aug. 2011.

Comment: You’ve given me an entirely new sense for the verb *cover*.

Comment: Really? My first thought when reading the title was "for cover".